# FFmpeg copying from udp to rtsp

Tags: ffmpeg, udp, protocols, rtsp, live-streaming

So I have a (live)video stream on udp://10.5.5.100:8463 and I copy it to udp://localhost:1000.

```
ffmpeg -f mpegts -i "udp://10.5.5.100:8554?fifo_size=10000" -f mpegts -vcodec copy udp://localhost:1000/go
```

And it works fine in VLC but Wirecast doesn't accept udp://..., but it accepts rtsp://...

but I don't now much about ffmpeg, so I only changed udp to rtsp

```
ffmpeg -f mpegts -i "udp://10.5.5.100:8554?fifo_size=10000" -f mpegts -vcodec copy rtsp://localhost:1000/go
```

But it doesn't work and outputs this

```
rtsp://localhost:1000/go: Protocol not found
```

Thank you for answers!!

Answer (score 2):

If you put '-f rtsp' instead of '-f mpegts' ffmpeg will try to establish connection to this url.
Proper solution with ffmpeg suite will be complex and include 'ffserver' as rtsp server and 'ffmpeg' as media stream source for the ffserver.

Much more simpler solution is to try vlc:

```
 cvlc -vvv udp://10.5.5.100:8554?fifo_size=10000 --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://localhost:1000/go}'
```

It starts RTSP server on localhost:1000 and retransmits data from UDP to the clients connected to this RTSP server.